# Send email notification to submitter of approval process after record was approved

Tags: email, approval-process

I wonder how to send email notification to submitter of approval process. When I trying to set email alert I see only Creator/Owner and nothing similar to Submitter. What will be the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of one of the approach.
You can create a custom field and in the initial submission action populate that field with current user. The current user will be the one who submitted the record for approval.
And use that field to send out the mail when record approves.

Comment: I wonder if there is any possibility to get Information about submitter without adding additional fields?

Comment: I think currently this is the Salesforce limitation.

Comment: Record triggered flow started when status change to Approved will be good idea?

Comment: But in that case you will not be having submitter email. You will get approver email address.

Comment: Oh. Yes. User which run the flow will be approver.

Comment: But I will be able to query: SELECT TargetObjectId, SubmittedById FROM ProcessInstance WHERE TargetObjectId = '<some SFDC record ID>'

Comment: I guess it will work you can give it a try.